# How to convert RewriteCond rules so they work in Lighttpd?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

How can I convert this Apache rewrite rules so they work on Lighttpd? This is in fact a .htaccess file, and I need to put those in a lighttpd.conf file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule www.(.*) web.php?url=$1
RewriteRule sitemap/(.*) mapdi.php?page=$1
RewriteRule tags_(.*)\.html$ tags.php?keywords=$1
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-page-([^-]*)\.html$ tags.php?keywords=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap_([^-]*)\.html$ sitemap_web.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.html$ sitemap.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy\.html$ privacy.php$1 [L]
```

I converted some part of the code, but not sure how I can convert:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

....
....

Here is what I could convert:

```
url.rewrite-once = (

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

    "www.(.*)" => "web.php?url=$1",
    "sitemap/(.*)" => "mapdi.php?page=$1",
    "tags_(.*)\.html$" => "tags.php?keywords=$1",
    "^([^-]*)-page-([^-]*)\.html$" => "tags.php?keywords=$1&page=$2",
    "^sitemap_([^-]*)\.html$" => "sitemap_web.php?page=$1",
    "^sitemap\.html$" => "sitemap.php$1",
    "^privacy\.html$" => "privacy.php$1"
)
```